# RenderScript - is it good practice to call Allocation.destroy() on every Allocation object created when you're done with it?

Tags: android, renderscript

I've been having problems with memory management while using RenderScript, so I figured that since `Allocation.createFromBitmap()/createTyped()` consumes memory, `Allocation.destroy()` frees the memory consumed by it.

Is it good practice to do so, and what else is good practice for RenderScript-based programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The finalizer of Allocation will reclaim the memories when GC happens.

However, yes, it is a good practice to destroy Allocations when you don't need them any more.

One comment: it is usually a good practice to call [Allocation.createFromBitmap(RenderScript rs, Bitmap b)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/Allocation.html#createFromBitmap(android.renderscript.RenderScript,%20android.graphics.Bitmap)) when creating Allocations from a bitmap. It would make the Allocation share the data with the bitmap, thus you don't need to copy back and forth, as long as the stride of the bitmap is aligned on a 32bytes or 16bytes boundary.

Comment: So the bitmap's width and height have to be duplicates or multiples of 16 and are powers of two (assuming that one pixel is one byte)?

Comment: Only the width of the bitmap matters.

Comment: Only the width, so the height can be any value above zero?

Comment: @MiaoWang Can USAGE_SHARED supported for non-bitmap data? It seems to work on CPU, but fails on GPU enabled renderscript drivers. Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50548979/15139