# Renderscript fails on GPU enabled driver if USAGE_SHARED

Tags: android, performance, signal-processing, renderscript, android-renderscript

We are using renderscript for audio dsp processing. It is simple and improves performance significantly for our use-case. But we run into an annoying issue with `USAGE_SHARED` on devices that have custom driver with GPU execution enabled.

As you may know, [`USAGE_SHARED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/Allocation#usage_shared) flag makes the renderscript allocation to reuse the given memory without having to create a copy of it. As a consequence, it not only saves memory, in our case, improves performance to desired level.

The following code with `USAGE_SHARED` works fine on default renderscript driver (`libRSDriver.so`). With custom driver (`libRSDriver_adreno.so`) `USAGE_SHARED` does not reuse given memory and thus data.

This is the code that makes use of `USAGE_SHARED` and calls renderscript kernel

```
void process(float* in1, float* in2, float* out, size_t size) {
  sp<RS> rs = new RS();
  rs->init(app_cache_dir);

  sp<const Element> e = Element::F32(rs);
  sp<const Type> t = Type::create(rs, e, size, 0, 0);

  sp<Allocation> in1Alloc = Allocation::createTyped(
                rs, t,
                RS_ALLOCATION_MIPMAP_NONE, 
                RS_ALLOCATION_USAGE_SCRIPT | RS_ALLOCATION_USAGE_SHARED,
                in1);

  sp<Allocation> in2Alloc = Allocation::createTyped(
                rs, t,
                RS_ALLOCATION_MIPMAP_NONE, 
                RS_ALLOCATION_USAGE_SCRIPT | RS_ALLOCATION_USAGE_SHARED,
                in2);

  sp<Allocation> outAlloc = Allocation::createTyped(
                rs, t,
                RS_ALLOCATION_MIPMAP_NONE, 
                RS_ALLOCATION_USAGE_SCRIPT | RS_ALLOCATION_USAGE_SHARED,
                out);

  ScriptC_x* rsX = new ScriptC_x(rs);
  rsX->set_in1Alloc(in1Alloc);
  rsX->set_in2Alloc(in2Alloc);
  rsX->set_size(size);

  rsX->forEach_compute(in1Alloc, outAlloc);
}
```

NOTE: This variation of `Allocation::createTyped()` is not mentioned in the documentation, but code `rsCppStructs.h` has it. This is the allocation factory method that allows providing backing pointer and respects `USAGE_SHARED` flag. This is how it is declared:

```
/**
 * Creates an Allocation for use by scripts with a given Type and a backing pointer. For use
 * with RS_ALLOCATION_USAGE_SHARED.
 * @param[in] rs Context to which the Allocation will belong
 * @param[in] type Type of the Allocation
 * @param[in] mipmaps desired mipmap behavior for the Allocation
 * @param[in] usage usage for the Allocation
 * @param[in] pointer existing backing store to use for this Allocation if possible
 * @return new Allocation
 */
static sp<Allocation> createTyped(
            const sp<RS>& rs, const sp<const Type>& type,
            RsAllocationMipmapControl mipmaps, 
            uint32_t usage, 
            void * pointer);
```

This is the renderscript kernel

```
rs_allocation in1Alloc, in2Alloc;
uint32_t size;

// JUST AN EXAMPLE KERNEL
// Not using reduction kernel since it is only available in later API levels.
// Not sure if support library helps here. Anyways, unrelated to the current problem

float compute(float ignored, uint32_t x) {
  float result = 0.0f;
  for (uint32_t i=0; i<size; i++) {
    result += rsGetElementAt_float(in1Alloc, x) * rsGetElementAt_float(in2Alloc, size-i-1); // just an example computation
  }

  return result;
}
```

As mentioned, `out` doesn't have any of the result of the calculation. 
[`syncAll(RS_ALLOCATION_USAGE_SHARED)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/Allocation.html#syncAll(int)) also didn't help.

The following works though (but much slower)

```
void process(float* in1, float* in2, float* out, size_t size) {
  sp<RS> rs = new RS();
  rs->init(app_cache_dir);

  sp<const Element> e = Element::F32(rs);
  sp<const Type> t = Type::create(rs, e, size, 0, 0);

  sp<Allocation> in1Alloc = Allocation::createTyped(rs, t);
  in1Alloc->copy1DFrom(in1);

  sp<Allocation> in2Alloc = Allocation::createTyped(rs, t);
  in2Alloc->copy1DFrom(in2);

  sp<Allocation> outAlloc = Allocation::createTyped(rs, t);

  ScriptC_x* rsX = new ScriptC_x(rs);
  rsX->set_in1Alloc(in1Alloc);
  rsX->set_in2Alloc(in2Alloc);
  rsX->set_size(size);

  rsX->forEach_compute(in1Alloc, outAlloc);
  outAlloc->copy1DTo(out);
}
```

Copying makes it to work, but in our testing, copying back and forth significantly degrades performance.

If we switch off GPU execution through `debug.rs.default-CPU-driver` system property, we could see that custom driver works well with desired performance.

Aligning memory given to renderscript to 16,32,.., or 1024, etc did not help to make the custom driver respect USAGE_SHARED.

#### Question

So, our question is this: How to make this kernel work for devices that use custom renderscript driver that enables GPU execution?

Comment: have you tried adding RS_ALLOCATION_USAGE_GRAPHICS_TEXTURE?

Comment: Will try that. But I'm not dealing with graphics, but audio signals. Is RS_ALLOCATION_USAGE_GRAPHICS_TEXTURE relevant?

Comment: Checked with RS_ALLOCATION_USAGE_GRAPHICS_TEXTURE. Same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the copy even if you use USAGE_SHARED.

USAGE_SHARED is just a hint to the driver, it doesn’t have to use it.

If the driver does share the memory the copy will be ignored and performance will be the same.

Comment: I think you're right based on our experiments. I accepted the answer (and you'll get bounty in a day). What we could also conclude is that, in our case, performance isn't impacted by USAGE_SHARED with/without copy unlike what is perceived in the question. However, it is unclear why the performance is poor on GPU enabled driver. The default driver is about 4x faster than the custom driver! I really wish there is a way to revert to default driver at runtime.

Comment: Can you share more about your kernel/launch parameters and how you're measuring timing?

Comment: You can use RS_INIT_LOW_LATENCY in RS::init() to force using the default CPU driver.